# Transformar resultado em array e pegar todos os valores no "select"

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um problema na hora de criar um sistema, eu preciso fazer um select:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild = $get['guild'];
```

Transformar a variavel `$guild` em um array e pegar ela no outro `select`

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` != '$guild' AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
```

Exatamente o que eu preciso é que nesse `select` sejam removidos todos os resultados do `array`, mas não faço a menor idéia de como fazer isso.

Código completo:

```
<?php
require_once ("includes/connection.php");
require_once ("includes/start-session.php");
require_once ("includes/encript.php");
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$iusername = "Trabzera";
$userid = "10";
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE username='$iusername' AND `ip`='$ip'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
if ($row > 0) {
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild = $get['guild'];
#----------------------
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` != '$guild' AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count = 1;
echo '<div id="guild-central">Central da Guild</div>
<div id="guild-central-msg">Selecione abaixo a opção desejada:</div>
<menu id="create-guild">
<div id="create-guild-msg">Criar uma Guild</div>
<div id="create-guild-txt">Para criar uma Guild é necessário alguns requerimentos:</div>
<div id="create-guild-req1">- Nível 10+</div>
<div id="create-guild-req2">- 1000 KP (Knautiluz Points)</div>
<div id="create-guild-reqok">Caso atenda esses requsistos clique abaixo:</div>
<button id="create-guild-button">Criar uma Guild</button>
</menu>';
echo '<menu id="join-guild">
<div id="join-guild-msg">Juntar-se a uma Guild</div>';
#-----------------------------------------------------
if ($row > 0) {
while ($count <= $row) {
echo'
<script>
$("#guild-join-request-'.$count.'").click (function() {
var guildName = $("#guild-join-name-'.$count.'").html();
var src = $("#guild-join-icn-'.$count.'").attr("src");
var iusername = "'.$iusername.'";
var userid = "'.$userid.'";
$.ajax({
url: "systems/join-guild.php",
type: "POST",
data: {iusername: iusername, userid: userid, guildName: guildName, src: src},
beforeSend: function() {
$("#sucess").html("Carregando...");
},
success: function (result) {
$("#user-painel-2").html(result);
} 
});
});
</script>'; 
echo'
<div id="guild-join-'.$count.'" class="guild-join">
<img src="'.$guild_icn.'" id="guild-join-icn-'.$count.'"></img>
<div id="guild-join-name-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-name">'.$guild_name.'</div>
<div id="guild-join-score-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-score" >- '.$score_result.'K</div>
<input style="cursor:pointer;" type="button" id="guild-join-request-'.$count.'" value="Solicitar" class="guild-join-request"></input>
<div id="guild-join-underline-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-underline"></div>
</div>';
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count++;
}
echo'<menu id="guild-request">
<div id="guild-request-msg">Solicitações Pendentes:</div>'; 
#---------------------------------------------------------------
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id` ='$userid'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count = 1;
if($row > 0) {
while ($count <= $row) {
echo'
<div id="guild-request-'.$count.'" class="guild-request">
<img src="'.$guild_icn.'" id="guild-request-icn-'.$count.'"></img>
<div id="guild-request-name-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-name" >'.$guild_name.'</div>
<div id="guild-request-score-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-score">- '.$score_result.'K</div>
<button id="guild-request-cancel-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-cancel">Cancelar</button>
<div id="guild-request-underline-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-underline"></div>
</div>';
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count++;
}
echo '</div>
</menu>';
} else {
echo'   
<menu id="guild-request">
<div id="guild-request-msg">Solicitações Pendentes:</div>
<div id="no-requests">Nenhuma solicitação pendente.</div>
</menu></menu>';    
}
#---------------------------------------------------------------
} else {
echo "Ainda não existe nenhuma guild."; 
}
} else {
echo "Erro.";   
}
```

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem... você nao esta conseguindo fazer com que a solicitação suma na hora do clique? ou é como a solicitação não tivesse sido enviada?

Comment: Não, por exemplo: o usuário clica em solicitar, cadastra a solicitação no BD, ai quando atualizar a página a opção de solicitar aquela Guild some ali de cima, e vai pra baixo como na imagem, mas só um resultado está sumindo, o resto continua.

Comment: Ai aquele código de cima, é o que exibe as solicitaçoes e o de baixo sao as pendentes? Voce verificou se esta enviando a solicitaçao?

Comment: Dei uma editada na pergunta, não sei se melhorou. A solicitação é enviada, cadastrada. Depois que atualiza só um resultado some das opções de guilds, o resto continua como solicitar mesmo que elas já tenham sido solicitadas. A solicitação está sendo enviada normalmente, tanto que ela aparece ali em baixo, mas como ele já solicitou deveria sumir ali de cima... :/

Comment: Seria bom se você colocasse da forma com que esta na foto, o código dela. Porque esta dificil de compreender, mas sei onde pode estar o possível erro, pois voce estra trabalhando com array em resultado, e se esse resultado resulta em varios dados, e voce nao usar uma estrutura de repetição, voce simplesmente só pegará um registro que é o que parece estar acontecendo

Comment: O metodo [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) do `mysqli` retorna ***uma*** linha do resultado como um array associativo, numerico ou ambos. Ou seja, voce esta pegando apenas o primeiro resultado da sua query.  Acho que o [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) deva ser util no seu caso.

Comment: Editei toda a pergunta. É isso mesmo Pantera, eu preciso transformar as rows em um array pra pegar na hora do outro select, mas não sei como fazer, não entendo muito sobre arrays...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui estao algumas modificacoes que eu sugiro, para que seu codigo funcione da forma que pretende.

Como ja mencionado, o `fetch_array` retorna apenas uma linha da query ou `NULL` caso nao haja mais nada a ser preenchido (seja pelo resultado vazio ou por ter chegado ao fim do resultado das linhas retornadas pela base). Se usarmos o `fetch_all`, que retorna, por padrao, todos os resultados da query em um array numerico, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");   
$guilds = $select->fetch_all();
$row = $select->num_rows;
if ($row > 0) {
  $guild = implode("', '", array_column($guilds, "guild"));
  $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` NOT IN('$guild') AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Nessa parte do codigo, executamos a query para pegar todas as guildas que o usuario esta inserido/pendente:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");   
$guilds = $select->fetch_all();
```

Entao verificamos a quantidade de resultado (`if ($row > 0)`), caso ele seja maior que zero, montamos a nova query para filtrar as guildas que o usuario nao esta inserido/pendente. Comecando com o uso do [array_column](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) para pegarmos apenas o valor que nos interessa do resultado (`guild`) e, juntamente com o [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php), formamos uma string separada por virgula com todas as guildas que o usuario pertence/esta pendente:

```
$guild = implode("', '", array_column($guilds, "guild"));
```

Para nossa quary, usaremos o `NOT IN()` para filtrarmos pelas guildas que nao queremos no resultando:

```
"SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` NOT IN('$guild') AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5"
```

De resto acredito que pode manter seu codigo como esta, utilizando o `fetch_array`. Codigo completo:

```
<?php
require_once ("includes/connection.php");
require_once ("includes/start-session.php");
require_once ("includes/encript.php");
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$iusername = "Trabzera";
$userid = "10";
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE username='$iusername' AND `ip`='$ip'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
if ($row > 0) {
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");   
$guilds = $select->fetch_all();
$row = $select->num_rows;
if ($row > 0) {
  $guild = implode("', '", array_column($guilds, "guild"));
  $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` NOT IN('$guild') AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5");
  $row = $select->num_rows;
  $get = $select->fetch_array();
  $guild_name = $get['guild'];
  $guild_icn = $get['icn'];
  $guild_score = $get['score'];
  $score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
  $count = 1;
}
echo '<div id="guild-central">Central da Guild</div>
<div id="guild-central-msg">Selecione abaixo a opção desejada:</div>
<menu id="create-guild">
<div id="create-guild-msg">Criar uma Guild</div>
<div id="create-guild-txt">Para criar uma Guild é necessário alguns requerimentos:</div>
<div id="create-guild-req1">- Nível 10+</div>
<div id="create-guild-req2">- 1000 KP (Knautiluz Points)</div>
<div id="create-guild-reqok">Caso atenda esses requsistos clique abaixo:</div>
<button id="create-guild-button">Criar uma Guild</button>
</menu>';
echo '<menu id="join-guild">
<div id="join-guild-msg">Juntar-se a uma Guild</div>';
#-----------------------------------------------------
if ($row > 0) {
while ($count <= $row) {
echo'
<script>
$("#guild-join-request-'.$count.'").click (function() {
var guildName = $("#guild-join-name-'.$count.'").html();
var src = $("#guild-join-icn-'.$count.'").attr("src");
var iusername = "'.$iusername.'";
var userid = "'.$userid.'";
$.ajax({
url: "systems/join-guild.php",
type: "POST",
data: {iusername: iusername, userid: userid, guildName: guildName, src: src},
beforeSend: function() {
$("#sucess").html("Carregando...");
},
success: function (result) {
$("#user-painel-2").html(result);
} 
});
});
</script>'; 
echo'
<div id="guild-join-'.$count.'" class="guild-join">
<img src="'.$guild_icn.'" id="guild-join-icn-'.$count.'"></img>
<div id="guild-join-name-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-name">'.$guild_name.'</div>
<div id="guild-join-score-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-score" >- '.$score_result.'K</div>
<input style="cursor:pointer;" type="button" id="guild-join-request-'.$count.'" value="Solicitar" class="guild-join-request"></input>
<div id="guild-join-underline-'.$count.'" class="guild-join-underline"></div>
</div>';
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count++;
}
echo'<menu id="guild-request">
<div id="guild-request-msg">Solicitações Pendentes:</div>'; 
#---------------------------------------------------------------
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id` ='$userid'");
$row = $select->num_rows;
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count = 1;
if($row > 0) {
while ($count <= $row) {
echo'
<div id="guild-request-'.$count.'" class="guild-request">
<img src="'.$guild_icn.'" id="guild-request-icn-'.$count.'"></img>
<div id="guild-request-name-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-name" >'.$guild_name.'</div>
<div id="guild-request-score-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-score">- '.$score_result.'K</div>
<button id="guild-request-cancel-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-cancel">Cancelar</button>
<div id="guild-request-underline-'.$count.'" class="guild-request-underline"></div>
</div>';
$get = $select->fetch_array();
$guild_name = $get['guild'];
$guild_icn = $get['icn'];
$guild_score = $get['score'];
$score_result = round($guild_score/1000);
$count++;
}
echo '</div>
</menu>';
} else {
echo'   
<menu id="guild-request">
<div id="guild-request-msg">Solicitações Pendentes:</div>
<div id="no-requests">Nenhuma solicitação pendente.</div>
</menu></menu>';    
}
#---------------------------------------------------------------
} else {
echo "Ainda não existe nenhuma guild."; 
}
} else {
echo "Erro.";   
}
```

#### Update

Caso tenha problemas com o metodo `fetch_all` (seja pela ausencia do driver nativo do MySQL no seu servidor ou pela versao do PHP), pode percorrer o resultado com o `fetch_assoc` ou o  proprio `fetch_array`:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");   
$guilds = [];
while ($guild = $select->fetch_array()) {
  $guilds[] = $guild['guild'];
}
if ($row > 0) {
  $guild = implode("', '", array_column($guilds, "guild"));
  $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `guild` WHERE `guild` NOT IN('$guild') AND `user_id` != '$userid' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: +1 por toda a explicação. Mas quando executo o código a tela vem branca, percebi que depois do fetch_all nada mais funciona, nem se eu der um var_dump($guilds); É como se depois dele congelasse. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @JacksonAntunes Com o seu codigo original funciona normalmente?

Comment: Sim, funciona, exceto pela parte de remover os resultados indesejados. Não sei exatamente qual o problema com a tela branca, quando o LocalHost tentou me ajudar foi a mesma coisa, depois do fetch_all nenhum comando funciona, tudo resulta em tela branca. tentei colocar em echo "Teste"; depois dele mas não vai... var_dump também não funciona.

Comment: Para ajudar a debugar, poderia adicionar essas duas linhas no topo do seu arquivo? 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
Aparentemente seu PHP nao esta com a apresentacao de erros habilitada.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar!

Comment: Opa, agora foi: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /home/u756477073/public_html/systems/guild.php on line 14

Comment: 13 $row = $select->num_rows;
14 $guilds = $select->fetch_all();

são as linhas 13 e 14...

Comment: @JacksonAntunes sabe me dizer a versao do PHP que esta usando?

Comment: Meu host diz que é a versão 5.5

Comment: Aparentemente o metodo `fetch_all` exige o pacote msqlnd (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#88031). Qual sistema operacional esta usando? Assim podemos verificar se voce ja tem essa extensao instalada, e se nao tiver podemos instalar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50348/discussion-between-jackson-antunes-and-pantera).